# Can I have plus or minus when doing cases?

Tags: haskell

Could I put a case to be within a certain range or another number?

say
...

```
case x of
   +/- 3 -> yes
```

...

Would that be something Haskell should understand?

Update: In short, would i be able to match to an interval rather than a number?

Answer (score 5):

no but you can use `abs` and turn it around:

for a interval around `p` with radius `r`  you can use

```
if abs (x-p) <= r then yes else ...
```

example:

```
Prelude> let inInterval p r x = abs (x-p) <= r
Prelude> inInterval 5 3 1
False
Prelude> inInterval 5 3 2
True
Prelude> inInterval 5 3 8
True
Prelude> inInterval 5 3 9
False
```

Comment: can i do something like sqrt (abs 2)?

Comment: well that`s just the square root of 2 (= 1.4142135623730951) - so what is the point of using abs or the value?

Comment: just in case: `abs x` is the absolute value of `x` - for numbers you usually have `abs p = p` for *positive* `p` and `abs n = (-n)` for *negative* `n` ( `abs 0 = 0`)